# Send Array in GSON

Tags: java, gson

I need to send an array GSON.
Here's how to request looks in REST.

```
{
"session_id":"9658179abdcc29eb12cdb1a35f91a11a",
"list":[
    "112",
    "112"
]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
JSONObject requestObject = new JSONObject();
requestObject.put("session_id", session_id);
requestObject.put("list", list);
return requestObject.toString();
```

where list is ArrayList.

I get an error:

```
 Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 8 column 1
```

What am I doing wrong?
Sorry, I'm new to GSON.

Comment: Did you look at the GSON docs first? https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples

Comment: Are you trying to parse a JSon string or you need to produce a JSon string?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
return new Gson().toJson(requestObject);
```

instead of:

```
return requestObject.toString();
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing.

@Override
protected int read(String jsonString) throws IOException {
setUserList(new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, UserList.class));
return getUserList().getError().getCode();
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. Please be more specific and clar. I'm assuming you want to use Gson to generate a JSONArray like:

```
{
"session_id":"9658179abdcc29eb12cdb1a35f91a11a",
"list":[
    "112",
    "112"
]
}
```

Would be something like:

```
        final JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("session_id", "9658179abdcc29eb12cdb1a35f91a11a");
        final JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
        jsonArray.add(new JsonPrimitive("112"));
        jsonArray.add(new JsonPrimitive("112"));
        jsonObject_MatchEventDiscussion.add("list", jsonArray);
```

Notes:

- Realize you can do now jsonObject.toString() that is a handy method 
  to add the JsonArray to your POST requests as an String.
- JSONArray != JsonArray